# Multiple Sql Queries Same Field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table (Inventory_Line) where LID is auto increment and IID is a single number referring to the inventory date, PID is a numeric part#.  We use this table for inventory.

```
LID  IID  NAME    PID  QTY
---  ---  ------  ---  ---
1    1    Part A  213  12
2    1    Part B  200  15
3    2    Part A  213  9
4    2    Part B  200  7
```

We also have a table Order_Line

```
OLID  OID  NAME    PID  QTY
----  ---  ------  ---  ---
1     217  Part A  213  12
2     217  Part B  200  15
3     218  Part A  213  9
4     218  Part B  200  7
```

My goal is to show

```
((Previous Inventory Qty (Inventory_Line.IID=1)) AS PREV_INV + 
(ORDERED Qty (Order_Line.OID = 217 AND 218)) AS ORDERED - 
(Current Inventory Qty Inventory_Line.IID=2) AS CURRENT_INV) AS SOLD 
WHERE PID = X
```

The output would be like this:

```
PID  NAME    PREV_INV  ORDERED  CURRENT_INV  SOLD
---  ------  --------  -------  -----------  ----
213  Part A  12        21       9            24
```

We are using MS Access and I have some experience with Joins but I am kind of stuck on how to pull this off.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @HansUP added an example of what I would consider correct output to original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you thinking of something on these lines?

```
SELECT t.pid,
       Nz([pi].[qty], 0) + Nz([o].[qty], 0) - Nz([s].[qty], 0) AS dat
FROM   (((SELECT DISTINCT pid
         FROM   inventory_line) AS t
         LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
                    FROM   inventory_line
                    WHERE  iid = 2) AS pi
           ON t.pid = pi.pid)
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
                   FROM   inventory_line
                   WHERE  iid = 3) AS s
          ON t.pid = s.pid)
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
                  FROM   order_line
                  WHERE  oid = 217
                          OR oid = 218) AS o
         ON t.pid = o.pid
WHERE  (( ( t.pid ) = [Enter:] ))
```

The above needs some work, but what should be done would be clearer with more input on the desired output.

---

Re comments

```
SELECT t.pid,
       t.name,
       pi.qty,
       o.q,
       s.qty,
       Nz([pi].[qty]) + Nz([o].[q]) - Nz([s].[Qty]) AS sold
FROM   (((SELECT DISTINCT pid,
                         [Name]
         FROM   inventory_line) AS t
         LEFT JOIN (SELECT pid,
                           qty
                    FROM   inventory_line
                    WHERE  iid = 1) AS pi
           ON t.pid = pi.pid)
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT pid,
                          qty
                   FROM   inventory_line
                   WHERE  iid = 2) AS s
          ON t.pid = s.pid)
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT pid,
                         SUM(qty) AS q
                  FROM   order_line
                  WHERE  oid = 217
                          OR oid = 218
                  GROUP  BY pid) AS o
         ON t.pid = o.pid
WHERE  (( ( t.pid ) = [Enter:] ))
```

Comment: Well from reading this SQL the query would be based on a inputed pid,  What I would like is a full list of all pid so perhaps I will omit the last line and try testing that.  Thats a lot I knew this was more complicated than I have experience with SQl wise.

Comment: I added an example of output desired in original post if that helps.

Comment: I have added another example.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't work out the where the 24 in the SOLD column comes from but here is another solution for the rest

```
SELECT Order_Line.PID, Order_Line.NAME, DLookUp("[QTY]","[Order_Line]","[OID]=" & [OID]-1 & " AND PID=" & [PID]) AS PREV_INV, DSum("[QTY]","[Order_Line]","[PID]=" & [PID]) AS ORDERED, Order_Line.QTY AS CURRENT_INV FROM Order_Line;
```